# Add a new item to a list with multiple data types C#

Tags: c#, list

I have a `List` that looks like this:

```
private List<(string, string, int, string, string)> Students = new List<(string LastName, string FirstName, int ID, string Class, string Grade)>()
{
};
```

I want to be able to add some data to it like below:

```
Students.Add("Trump", "Donald", 0, "Making America Great Again", "C-");
```

But when I try that I get the following error:

```
No overload for method 'Add' takes 5 arguments
```

How can I use my `List` as intended?

Comment: You need to add a new tuple, not 5 separate objects. Also, it would probably be better to create a simple class to represent the object that you're storing.

Comment: I think it would also be worth asking the question of why you're using a Tuple at this point. This seems like very structured and related data, and your life will be much easier if you turn this into a struct or class.

Comment: Add additional parenthesis around tuple `Students.Add(("Trump", "Donald", 0, "Making America Great Again", "C-"));`

Comment: Thanks! I have it like this since I want to loop it and be able to export it to a .csv file for each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list is type `List<(string, string, int, string, string)>` so you must pass the `Add()` method a `(string, string, int, string, string)` which is a Tuple. Adding an extra set of parenthesis will fix your error.

`Students.Add(("Trump", "Donald", 0, "Making America Great Again", "C-"));`

As others have suggested in the comments, at this point you should consider creating a class or struct to represent the data.